# Дед Щукарь

Tags: этимология, литература, ономастика

Все помнят забавного деда Щукаря из "Поднятой целины". Но мне всегда было интересно: Щукарь - это фамилия или прозвище?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это прозвище. Получил его Щукарь в детстве после того, как, пытаясь откусить крючок с удочки рыболова, сам попался на удочку. Приведу отрывок полностью. Рассказывает сам дед Щукарь: «…Десятый год мне шел, и тут я был натурально пойматый на крючок… — На какой крючок? — удивился Давыдов, слушавший Щукарев рассказ не без внимания. — На обыкновенный, каким рыбу ловят. Был у нас в Гремячем в энту пору глухой и ветхий дед по прозвищу Купырь. Зимой он куропаток ловил венгерками и крыл шатериком, а летом так и пропадал на речке, удочками рыбалил. У нас речка тогда была глубже, и даже лапшиновская мельничушка об один постав на ней тогда стояла. Под плотиной сазаники водились и щуки огромные; вот дед, бывалоча, и сидит возля талового кустика с удочками. Разложит их штук семь, — на какую за червя ловит, на какую за тесто, а то и за живца щуку поджидает. Вот мы, ребятишки, и приладились у него крючки откусывать. Дед-то глухой, как камень, ему хучь в ухо мочись, все одно не услышит. Соберемся мы на речке, растелешимся вблизу деда за кустиком, и один из нас потихонечку в воду слезет, чтобы волны не пустить, поднырнет под дедовы удочки, крайнюю леску схватит — жик ее зубами, перекусит и обратно под кустом вынырнет. А дед выдернет удилищу, ажник задрожит весь, шамчит: «Опять откусила, треклятая? Ах ты, мати божия!» — это он про щуку думает и, натурально, злобствует, что крючка лишился. У него-то крючки лавошные, а нам, бывало, покупать не за что их, вот мы вокруг деда и промышляем. В один такой момент добыл я крючок и поинтересовался другой откусить. Вижу, дед занялся насадкой, я и нырнул. Только что потихонечку нашшупал леску и рот к ней приложил, а дед ка-ак смыканет удилищу вверх! Леска-то осмыгнулась у меня в руке, крючок и промзил верхнюю губу. Тут я кричать, а вода в рот льется. Дед же тянет удилищу, норовит меня вываживать. Я, конечно, от великой боли ногами болтаю, волокусь на крючке и уж чую, как дед под меня черпачок в воде подсовывает… Ну, тут я, натурально, вынырнул и реванул дурным голосом. Дед обмер, хочет крестное знамение сотворить и не могет, у самого морда стала от страха чернее чугуна. Да и как ему было не перепугаться? Тянул щуку, а вытянул парнишку. Стоял, стоял он, да, эх, как вдарится бечь!.. Чирики с ног ажник у него соскакивают! Я с этим крючком в губе домой прибыл. Отец крючок-то вырезал, а потом меня же и высек до потери сознательности. А спрашивается, что толку-то? Губа обратно срослась, но **с той поры и кличут меня Щукарем. Присохла на мне глупая эта кличка…**».

Кстати, в Ростове-на-Дону деду Щукарю поставлен памятник.